# Zooming disturbing drawn UIImage in UIView

Tags: iphone

I have UIView in which I am drawing UIImage

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [myImage drawInRect:rect];
}
```

This UIView is added on UIScrollView and returned as zoomable view i.e

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{   
    return iImageBgView;
}
```

Problem is coming when I do the zoom. Image which is drawn is getting shown pixelet i.e blur or disturbed. can anyone help me on "How to refresh / redraw this image"

I am manually refreshing / redrawing the image by calling

```
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

but no use. seems like it is taking the previous coordinate and draw as per that instead of updated coordinate.

Thanks,

Sagar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by removing this UIView and adding it again on scrollview.

This has been done on

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
   // Remove Imageview and add to Scrollview again
}
```